# What causes the huge runtime difference between these two functions?

Tags: python, recursion, caching, optimization, runtime

There's a huge difference in speed between these two recursive functions and I don't understand why. These are solutions for "The Grandest Staircase of Them All" from Google's Foobar. Essentially, you need to determine how many possible staircases can be made with n blocks (a staircase is a sequence of natural numbers in which each number is higher than the previous, with at least two "steps"—for instance, [1, 2, 3] is a staircase consisting of 6 blocks).

Here's the code I wrote:

```
def solution(n):
    return stairs(n, n)
    
def stairs(lastStair, n):
    if (n < 1):
        return (1 if n == 0 else 0)
    if (lastStair == 1):
        return 0 

    #recursively call stairs() for each possible next step height, and add the results together
    return sum([stairs(i, n - i) for i in range(1, lastStair)])

print(solution(200))
```

And here's what someone else wrote (taken from [here](https://jtp.io/2016/07/26/dynamic-programming-python.html)):

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def count(height, left):
    if left == 0:
        return 1
    if left < height:
        return 0
    return count(height + 1, left - height) + count(height + 1, left)

print(count(1, 200) - 1)
```

Both give correct results. However, my version is much, much slower. On my computer and with n = 200, solution(n) takes about two hours to run, whereas count(1, n) takes less than a second. I added the caching code to mine and the runtime remained the same. What causes solution(200) to take 10,000x as long? Or, perhaps the right question is, why doesn't caching benefit solution(200)?

Answer (score 0):

#### The @lru_cache is the difference.

**Short answer:**
 The lru_cache stores the results of the previous computations while your solution computes everything over and over again. Take some small stairs(e.g. stairs 20, 20) and look how many times do you compute stairs(4,4) or stairs(1,1). You will be surprised.

The more in depth explanation can be found for example [here](https://realpython.com/lru-cache-python/#:%7E:text=Python%27s%20%40lru_cache%20decorator%20offers%20a,entries%20will%20be%20ever%20evicted.). There they explain the @lru_cache magic with a similar problem. Also stairs, also recursion, however they are not building a new staircase but counting the ways of traversing it.